# How to spectate an arcade game in dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

I always wanted to spectate an arcade game played by my friend in dota 2. Its simple to spectate normal games, but when the same method is applied to spec an arcade game its gives an error.

Arcade game:- Epic Boss Fight
Error:- Version outdated

**Note:- i have the newest versions of dota-2 and Epic boss fight**

Comment: I think you can only spectate those arcade games, which run on dedicated server.

Answer (score -1):

So far I have only been able to spectate a game of Dota 10v10 when a friend was playing it. I don't think there is any other way to spectate others even if the mod is installed.

Comment: This doesn't provide any answer to my question.

Comment: So far there isn't any answer yet. However, I do realise that I should have commented instead of typing in the Answer section. New to StackExchange!